# Multiple search requests in multiple sites (Microsoft Graph API)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I'm making an application with [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) where the users [search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in **16 drives** on **16 different sites**. I have tried to make a [batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) job with all **16 search requests** in one **single batch job** like this:

```
{
 requests: {
    {
      id: driveId,
      method: 'GET',
      url: `/sites/${siteId}/drives/${driveId}/search(q='${query}')`
    }
      ,
    // Next request
        }
    }
```

But when I make search requests like this some of the requests get **throttled**. I have tried making the search request with **dependsOn** to make it sequentially. but then the batch job takes up to **20 seconds** which is way too long.

Is there any faster way to search in **16 drives** on **16 different sites** in **Microsoft Graph API**? I don't want search results from other drives than the specific drives.

Comment: What about sending 16 requests in parallel? If some requests get throttled, you can repeat those failed requests.

Comment: Async functions is not available in the javascript serverside apps i build in this CMS.